# Are you a boy? or a girl?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

Pokemon Black/White has been applauded for the improved storyline (well, for a Pokemon game). Are there any differences in being a male protagonist versus being a female protagonist? Or is it completely cosmetic in nature?

As suggested by Raven Dreamer, this is the situation I'm referencing:
[image: To illustrate]

Comment: lol @ the title...

Comment: @bwarner: While your title is just as funny, I prefer mine since it is lifted directly from the professor's opening.

Comment: @Rapida - you should totally add this picture to better illustrate your question: http://www.vgcats.com/super/images/080423.gif

Comment: @Rapida Apologies, I'm not actually familiar with the game to know the quote.

Comment: @RavenDreamer: Awesome, Done

Comment: @Rapida - yeah, didn't want to just edit it into your question without your permission.

Comment: yes, i am a boy or a girl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no differences in gameplay depending on what you chose.

Cosmetic-wise, the default menus if you are a girl are pink, and the menus are blue if you are male.  Also by default, the boy has hexagon-shapes on his C-Gear, and the girl has heart-shapes.

Comment: Aren't the menu colors changable?

Comment: You can also change the shapes on the c-gear by pushing the -gear- on the bottom screen while in edit mode

Comment: Are your friends/rivals different? If you choose boy, Cheren (male) is your main rival for battling, while Bianca seems to care more about taking care of Pokemon. If you choose the girl, is that still the same?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat That stays the same regardless of your gender in game.  There are no mechanical differences at all.